How can I find the session ID for a program instrumented with Microsoft.CodeCoverage?
I am collecting code coverage for C++ (from fuzz testing) using Microsoft.CodeCoverage.
Since the coverage does not terminate if the instrumented app crashes (which is how I flag a fuzz-test error), I have needed to move to server-mode coverage collection. This means I need a session ID for my coverage.
I am instrumenting for coverage using
Microsoft.CodeCoverage.Console.exe instrument <my_program.exe> --session-id <session_string>

In this mode, the session ID is built into the image when it is instrumented, and a second attempt at instrumenting will fail with:
Module was not instrumented. Reason: optimized_or_instrumented.

Two questions:

Can I determine in advance if the program has already been instrumented?
If so, how can I find the session ID it has been instrumented with?



Check if the program is already instrumented: You can try running the instrumentation command again. If you get an error saying it’s already instrumented, that confirms it. Another way is to inspect the program’s binary with tools like dumpbin (from Visual Studio) to look for coverage-related info.
Find the session ID: There’s no direct command to get the session ID from an instrumented program. You might be able to find it in coverage reports or logs. If not, you’ll need to re-instrument the program with a new session ID.


Re 1: yes, obviously - but I was hoping there was a way that didn't involve running the instrument command.

Re 2: the approach I am taking is to make the session ID based on the file name and modified time, so I can at least work it out. But it's a shame there's no way to interrogate it.
